# Cluster Shared Volumes Mount Point

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, failovercluster

I am using Cluster Shared Volumes on Windows Server 2008 R2 with Hyper-V.  The different volumes available have different sizes, and are physically located on different disks on the SAN.  These volumes defaulted to labels such as C:\ClusterStorage\Volume1.  I know that it is not possible / recommended to change where the CSV mount points are (C:\ClusterStorage), but I want to change the rest of the path to be a more useful name than "Volume1".

In the Failover Cluster Manager, under Cluster Shared Volumes, I can see these CSVs, and they are working just fine.  When I go into their properties, I can see a list, which has the mount point listed, but the entries are not modifiable.

How can I change the mount point of a Cluster Shared Volume in Windows Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just rename the mount points like any regular folder in Windows: Right-click the mount point in Windows explorer and select rename.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to mark the answer as correct, I wasn't able to try it out till today.  It really is as simple as renaming the mount point just like you would rename any other folder.  The only gotcha is that Hyper-V and VMM don't see the change, and so you really should clear the volume before you rename it, or expect some pain and down time as a result.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to move the VMs to another mount point, then you can rename the mount point and then move the VMs back to it.

Comment: That makes sense, as I understand that you can't make a CSV out of a disk that has VMs on it.  However, I'm not understanding how to change the mount point at all, even when it is empty.  Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: You'll want to change it in Computer Manager's Disk Management I think.  (I don't have a Hyper-V box handy to look at.)  Just remove the existing mount point reference and add in a new one.  You'll probably have to remove it from the cluster administrator first.